# Displaying imagebuttons on screen

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, imagebutton, chess

I am trying to create a chess app in C# using Xamarin.Forms. Right now I am trying to implement the functionality of highlighting and moving pieces. I made code which should display every possible move upon clicking a piece as a clickable image button (clicking those buttons would make the move) however it does not happen and I am really not sure why.
This is the code which I think is necessary to understand my problem:

```
protected virtual void OnPieceClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var pieceButton = (ImageButton)sender;

            //debug
            Console.WriteLine($"_chessboardView is null: {_chessboardView == null}");
            if (_chessboardView != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"_possibleMoveButtons is null: {_chessboardView._possibleMoveButtons == null}");
            }

            Piece clickedPiece = null;
         for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++)
            {
                Piece piece = _chessBoard.Board[row, col];
                if (piece != null && piece.PieceButton == pieceButton)
                {
                    clickedPiece = piece;
                    _currentRow = row;
                    _currentCol = col;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (clickedPiece != null)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        
        var possibleMoves = GetPossibleMoves(_currentRow, _currentCol, _chessBoard.Board);

            //debug
            Console.WriteLine($"Number of possible moves for clicked piece: {possibleMoves.Count}");

        foreach (var move in possibleMoves)
        {
            var moveButton = new ImageButton
            {
                Source = "possible_move", // TODO: change pic
                BackgroundColor = Color.Red,
                CommandParameter = move
            };
            moveButton.Clicked += OnMoveClicked;

                _chessboardView._possibleMoveButtons.Add(moveButton);
            _chessboardView._moveButtons.Add(moveButton);
            _chessboardView.Children.Add(moveButton, move.col, move.row);

                //debug
                Console.WriteLine($"Added move button at row {move.row}, col {move.col}");
        }
    }
```

```
public void UpdateBoard()
        {
            // Remove previous piece images from the board
            foreach (ImageButton pieceButton in _pieceButtons)
            {
                Children.Remove(pieceButton);
            }
            foreach (ImageButton moveButton in _moveButtons)
            {
                Children.Remove(moveButton);
            }
            foreach (ImageButton possibleMoveButton in _possibleMoveButtons)
            {
                Children.Remove(possibleMoveButton);
            }

            _possibleMoveButtons.Clear();
            _moveButtons.Clear();
            _pieceButtons.Clear();

            //debug
            if (_chessBoard == null)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ChessBoard is null");
                return;
            }

            if (_chessBoard.Board == null)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ChessBoard's Board is null");
                return;
            }

            for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++)
                {
                    Piece piece = _chessBoard.Board[col, row];
                    if (piece != null)
                    {
                        ImageButton pieceButton = piece.PieceButton;

                        _pieceButtons.Add(pieceButton);
                        Children.Add(pieceButton, col, row);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I tried placing breakpoints in the code to see if the code even runs and it seems that it runs correctly, it's just the images don't display on the chessboard.
I really don't know what to do here. Thank you so much for your help in advance!

EDIT: I'm also adding xaml code and the methods for generating my chessboard if that's helpful:

```
<StackLayout>
    <local:ChessboardView x:Name="szachownica"
              ChessBoard="{Binding CurrentChessBoard}"
              RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0"
              Margin="20"
              HeightRequest="{Binding Path=Width, Source={x:Reference szachownica}}"
              InputTransparent="False">
        
    </local:ChessboardView>
    <Button Text="Previous move" Command="{Binding UndoMoveCommand}" />
    <Button Text="New Game" Command="{Binding NewGameCommand}" />
    <Button Text="New Game (vs AI)" Command="{Binding NewGameAICommand}" />
    <Button Text="New Game 960" Command="{Binding NewGame960Command}" />
</StackLayout>
```

```
public ChessboardView()
    {
        _possibleMoveButtons = new List<ImageButton>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
            ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
        }

        for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++)
            {
                BoxView square = new BoxView
                {
                    BackgroundColor = (row + col) % 2 == 0 ? Color.White : Color.Gray
                };

                Children.Add(square, col, row);
            }
        }
    }
```

```
    public ChessBoard()
        {
            Board = new Piece[8, 8];
            InitializeBoard();
            
            for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++)
                
                {
                    Piece piece = Board[x, y];
                    if (piece != null)
                    {
                        piece.SetChessBoardAndChessboardView(this, _chessboardView);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Too much code to have any idea what is wrong. Start with something simple: Can you click a button, and add one ImageButton to Children, and get that to display? If not, add a new section to question, with just the code to do that.

Comment: Please also put the relevant xaml code, which may help us reproduce your issue.

Comment: May I ask how you get _chessboardView in ChessBoard? Is it the same as that initialized in xaml?  If they are not the same, then the image button cannot show.

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT _chessboardView in ChessBoard comes from this line `protected ChessboardView _chessboardView;`.

Comment: okay, so when and how  do you set the value for _chessboardView in ChessBoard class?

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT I have the method in my Piece class
`public void SetChessBoardAndChessboardView(ChessBoard chessBoard, ChessboardView chessboardView)
        {
            _chessBoard = chessBoard;
            _chessboardView = chessboardView;

            //debug
            Console.WriteLine($"SetChessBoardAndChessboardView called. _chessBoard is null: {_chessBoard == null}, _chessboardView is null: {_chessboardView == null}");
        }`
it gets called in ChessBoard().

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT I uploaded some of my files to github [link](https://github.com/pakaccio/MyChessTraining) It's probably easier to look through them there. Thank you for your patience :)
Note: some of the methods/classes are completely useless there, because I used this project for learning different things and ended up resigning from some methods, but didn't delete them yet.

Comment: @pakaccio I post an answer. Please have a look. If you have any question, free to ask me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your .cs file,

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = new ChessViewModel();

        var viewModel = new ChessViewModel();
        var chessboardView = new ChessboardView();
        chessBoard = new ChessBoard(chessboardView);
        viewModel.ChessboardView = chessboardView;
        viewModel.CurrentChessBoard = chessBoard;
    }
```

You define two different `ChessViewModel` instance. One is for BindingContext. Another is useless. Then you create a new `ChessboardView` instance. That's not the same as the one (named "szachownica") in xaml. So the imagebutton will not show on "szachownica".

You may change the .cs file like the following:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    ChessViewModel viewModel;
    private ChessBoard chessBoard;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        viewModel = new ChessViewModel();
        this.BindingContext = viewModel;

        chessBoard = new ChessBoard(this.szachownica);
        viewModel.ChessboardView = this.szachownica;
        viewModel.CurrentChessBoard = chessBoard;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!